# Added extra SATA 6Gbit/s SSD drive, Windows 7 doesn't detect device, USB 3.0 device now runs slow

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, sata, disk-management

Added in an extra SATA 6Gbit/s SSD drive to my Windows 7 machine. Now two 6G/s SSDs - main one 64GB and this new 256GB. BIOS can see both. However when I run Windows 7 disk management tool it doesn't get past 'Loading disk configuration information' stage.

Also my external USB3.0 HDD now reads extremely slowly since I added the new SSD.

Any idea what's happening and how to fix?

Comment: Sometimes a bad disk (or loose connection on the cable, or broken cable, or broken SATA controller, or...) can cause I/O errors trying to read the disk, which can stall the entire operating system in extreme cases. This can cause the disk not to detect, the disk management snapin to hang, and making the USB HDD slow.

Answer (score 0):

My SM Bus driver wasn't installed. Downloaded appropriate driver from Intel, disconnected a few other drives while I installed the new one and now works fine.